# Hibernate Many To Many Mapping Persistence Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

Have got Two Tables Goal with Goal_Key and Initiative with Initiative_Key and an association table Goal_Initiative containing Goal_Key and Intiative_Key.

Below is from Table1 i.e Goal (removed setter getters) .

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GOAL")
@NamedQuery(name = "get_goal", 
  query = "SELECT goal FROM Goal goal ")
public class Goal {

/** The strategic_ goal_ key. */
@Column(name = "GOAL_KEY")
private String Goal_Key;

/** The strategic_ goal_ name. */
@Column(name = "GOAL_NM")
private String strategic_Goal_Name;

/** The client initiatives. */
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "goal_initiative", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Goal_Key") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "initiative_Key") })
List<ClientInitiative> initiative = new ArrayList<ClientInitiative>();
```

Below is from Table2 i.e Initiative

```
 /**
 * The Class ClientInitiative.
 */
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "INIITATIVE")
 public class ClientInitiative {

/** The initiative_ key. */
@Column(name = "INITIATIVE_KEY")
private String initiative_Key;

/** The initiative_Key_Name. */
@Column(name = "INITIATIVE_KEY_NM")
private String initiative_Key_Name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="clientInitiative")
List<StrategicGoal> strategicGoals = new ArrayList<StrategicGoal>();
```

This is my implementation Class

```
   @Repository
   public class GoalDAOImpl extends BaseDaoImpl{

@Override
@NamedQueryTarget("get_goal")
public List<Goal> getGoals(String planUnitKey) {

    List<Goal> goals = null;
    try {
        goals = (List<Goal>) getEntityManager()
                .createNamedQuery("get_goal").getResultList();
        return strategicGoals;
    } catch (NoResultException noResult) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is always returning me an Error , Also Please find the below stacktrace why is i adding a new Column.ID to query . We dont have any column for ID in Goal Table

```
" Persistence.PersistenceException"
```

Got stuck into this Persistence Error. Any suggestions on the above.

Complete stacktrace

org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException:
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=T0.ID, DRIVER=3.52.95                 {prepstmnt 1029586270

```
    SELECT t0.id, t0.GOAL_KEY, t0.GOAL_NM 
    FROM CGSP.GOAL t0
```

} [code=-206, state=42703]SQLCA OUTPUT[Errp=SQLNQ075, Errd=-2145779603, 0, 0, 0, -10, 0]
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=T0.ID, DRIVER=3.52.95
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-206;42703;T0.ID, DRIVER=3.52.95
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-206;42703;T0.ID, DRIVER=3.52.95
FailedObject: SELECT goal FROM Goal goal [java.lang.String]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4827)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4787)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary.newStoreException(DB2Dictionary.java:563)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:136)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:118)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:70)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SelectResultObjectProvider.handleCheckedException(SelectResultObjectProvider.java:155)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.(EagerResultList.java:40)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1246)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1005)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:861)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:792)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:542)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:288)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:302)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at $Proxy49.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.sales.cgsp.dao.impl.GoalDAOImpl.getClientStrategicGoals(GoalDAOImpl.java:27)
    at com.ibm.sales.cgsp.dao.test.ClientStrategicGoalDAOTest.testGetDetails(ClientStrategicGoalDAOTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=T0.ID, DRIVER=3.52.95 {prepstmnt 1029586270 
SELECT t0.id, t0.GOAL_KEY, t0.GOAL_NM 
    FROM GOAL t0 
} [code=-206, state=42703]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:257)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:241)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$700(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:70)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection$LoggingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:1063)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:278)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$CancelPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JDBCStoreManager.java:1731)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:268)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.executeQuery(SelectImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:396)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:363)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion$UnionSelect.execute(LogicalUnion.java:427)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:230)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:220)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SelectResultObjectProvider.open(SelectResultObjectProvider.java:94)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.(EagerResultList.java:34)
    ... 43 more
NestedThrowables:
com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.nn: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=T0.ID, DRIVER=3.52.95
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ad.a(ad.java:666)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ad.a(ad.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ad.a(ad.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.rl.c(rl.java:2424)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.rl.d(rl.java:2401)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.rl.a(rl.java:1902)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.g(db.java:138)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.a(db.java:38)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.t.a(t.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.sb.h(sb.java:141)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.rl.Y(rl.java:1873)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.bc(sl.java:2526)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.e(sl.java:3227)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.Ob(sl.java:569)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.executeQuery(sl.java:543)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:280)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection$LoggingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:1061)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:278)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$CancelPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JDBCStoreManager.java:1731)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:268)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.executeQuery(SelectImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:396)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:363)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion$UnionSelect.execute(LogicalUnion.java:427)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:230)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:220)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SelectResultObjectProvider.open(SelectResultObjectProvider.java:94)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.(EagerResultList.java:34)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1246)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1005)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:861)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:792)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:542)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:288)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:302)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at $Proxy49.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.sales.cgsp.dao.impl.GoalDAOImpl.getClientStrategicGoals(GoalDAOImpl.java:27)
    at com.ibm.sales.cgsp.dao.test.ClientStrategicGoalDAOTest.testGetDetails(ClientStrategicGoalDAOTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-206;42703;T0.ID, DRIVER=3.52.95
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ad.a(ad.java:669)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ad.a(ad.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ad.a(ad.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.rl.c(rl.java:2424)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.rl.d(rl.java:2401)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.a(sl.java:2452)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.a(db.java:187)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.b(db.java:81)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.t.b(t.java:69)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.tb.c(tb.java:224)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.Yb(sl.java:2443)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.bc(sl.java:2527)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.e(sl.java:3227)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.Ob(sl.java:569)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.executeQuery(sl.java:543)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:280)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection$LoggingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:1061)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:278)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$CancelPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JDBCStoreManager.java:1731)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:268)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.executeQuery(SelectImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:396)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:363)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion$UnionSelect.execute(LogicalUnion.java:427)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:230)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:220)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SelectResultObjectProvider.open(SelectResultObjectProvider.java:94)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.(EagerResultList.java:34)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1246)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1005)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:861)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:792)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:542)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:288)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:302)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at $Proxy49.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.sales.cgsp.dao.impl.GoalDAOImpl.getClientStrategicGoals(GoalDAOImpl.java:27)
    at com.ibm.sales.cgsp.dao.test.ClientStrategicGoalDAOTest.testGetDetails(ClientStrategicGoalDAOTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-206;42703;T0.ID, DRIVER=3.52.95
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ad.a(ad.java:669)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ad.a(ad.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ad.a(ad.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.rl.c(rl.java:2424)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.rl.a(rl.java:1929)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.n(db.java:739)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.i(db.java:257)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.c(db.java:52)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.t.c(t.java:44)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.sb.i(sb.java:153)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.rl.ab(rl.java:1924)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.e(sl.java:3286)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.Ob(sl.java:569)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.executeQuery(sl.java:543)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:280)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection$LoggingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:1061)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:278)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$CancelPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JDBCStoreManager.java:1731)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:268)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.executeQuery(SelectImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:396)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:363)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion$UnionSelect.execute(LogicalUnion.java:427)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:230)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:220)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SelectResultObjectProvider.open(SelectResultObjectProvider.java:94)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.(EagerResultList.java:34)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1246)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1005)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:861)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:792)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:542)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:288)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:302)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at $Proxy49.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.sales.cgsp.dao.impl.GoalDAOImpl.getClientStrategicGoals(GoalDAOImpl.java:27)
    at com.ibm.sales.cgsp.dao.test.ClientStrategicGoalDAOTest.testGetDetails(ClientStrategicGoalDAOTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Comment: Providing the entire stack trace of your error will help us a lot better

Comment: @Pratik Added the complete stacktrace

Comment: Did you google the sqlerrorcode 206?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look up the error code you will find the following

1. The specified column is not a column of any of the source or target tables or views of the statement.
2. In a SELECT or DELETE statement, the specified column is not a column of any of the tables or views that are identified in a FROM clause in the statement.
3. A column list of an SQL data change statement specified the name of a column of the target table or view of the statement.
4. A qualified column name was specified, but the table designator that is specified as the qualifier is not defined in this context.
5. A correlated reference to a column was specified in an OLAP specification. Each column name that is referenced in an OLAP specification must unambiguously reference a column of the result table of the subselect that contains the OLAP specification.

In your case its point no 1. The column id is not a column of your GOAL table. Hence the issue.

Hibernate identifies Objects (in first and 2nd level cache) using the ID of the object, so an object without an ID cannot be represented in hibernate.

Comment: I missed adding @Id into the corresponding columns.. Thanks for guiding me

Comment: Pratik.. When I run it now.. there are no errors but only the values of Goal are getting populated not the Initiative Table.. there is mapping in the associate table Goal_Initiative .. which I have mentioned in my @ joinTable and @ joincolumn annotations .. Any help on why its empty

Comment: Pratik Fetch Type was not lazy changed to Eager Works Fine .. Thanks a lot for you Help and Suggestions

Comment: should we always use Fetching type as Eager . I tried to use Lazy but the Child object (Initiative) is not getting loaded at al .. Any suggestions

Comment: When you use Lazy the child objects will get loaded only when you call the respective getters of the Parent object. We should use lazy loading when we want to delay the retrieval till we actually use the object.